# iPad app crashes when downloading files to the device

Tags: ios, ipad, download, gdb, nsdata

I have a iPad app that downloads video's, images and pdf's from the backend, but after a while (after 400 mb of download) the app crashes and the console prints me gdb back. Down

here is a part of the write function that I am using for the video files.

*UPDATE*

The app does download all the files if I release the NSData object "mediaDataResponse", but gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCES error after downloading all files.

Any help?

```
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
                NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
                NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video"];

                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageCacheDirPath])
                {
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imageCacheDirPath 
                                              withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                                               attributes:nil
                                                                    error:NULL];
                }

                NSString *filename = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/video/%@.%@",cacheFileName,extensionstring]];
                [mediaDataResponse writeToFile:filename options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error];

                //Thumbnail
                NSArray *thumbpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
                NSString *thumbdocsPath = [thumbpaths objectAtIndex:0]; 
                NSString *thumbimageCacheDirPath = [thumbdocsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"thumbnail"];

                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:thumbimageCacheDirPath])
                {
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:thumbimageCacheDirPath 
                                              withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                                               attributes:nil
                                                                    error:NULL];
                }

                NSURL  *thumburl = [NSURL URLWithString:media.mediaThumbnail];
                NSData *thumburlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thumburl];

                NSString *thumbfilename = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/thumbnail/%@.jpg", thumbcacheFileName]];
                [thumburlData writeToFile:thumbfilename options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error];

            }
```

When you startup the app after the crash it just continues the download where it stopped. Anyone had the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give details on the crash report?

Comment: Let me check if I can find some more details of the crash report.

Comment: Also a detail. I am having this error as well while downloading the files. "SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (_selectionLayoutChangedByScrolling:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: _kCFURLConnectionPrivateRunLoopMode" Maybe it has something to do with the problem.

Comment: I am getting this as well. Mar 16 09:53:56 unknown ReportCrash[867] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-03-16-095356.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be trying to load all 400MB of file into memory (based on the NSData usage) which is probably not the right way to go (and corroborated by your `LowMemory` comment). You will probably want to have your own NSURLConnection delegate that opens a file upon receiving a response, and appends all bytes directly to that file (not keeping it in an NSData).

Comment: I was already trying to build something like this and I will try this out! Thanks for the answer!